# What is this fortran parameter declaration doing and why is it doing it?

Tags: fortran, declaration

I have a parameter being declared in a fortran header file like this:

```
parameter (param=((0-565)))
```

param always seems to be valued at 565. Basis tutorials on parameters don't include information about what the ((0-565)) actually means in this context and my google-fu isn't up to this challenge.

Comment: if param isn't declared, then implicit rules would make me think it gets the value `-565.0`, if declared as an integer `-565`

Comment: Any idea why someone would set it with ((0-595)) instead of just setting it to 0595?

Comment: assuming the popularity of implicit typing, I would think it's a type and `0.565` was meant, but then the `-` and `.` are difficult to swap. Or the programmer loved brackets and had a missing finger or something. Or there was a rule to precede negative numbers with 0. Your guess is as good as mine, or probably better since you have the rest of the code so you can see what param is doing.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not a typo and many of the other negative integer parameters are just declared as I'd expect. Looking at all of the parameter declarations, this is the only one like this, so maybe there used to be some other algebra in the parenthesis that got removed. The code is 20+ years old, so no telling who did it or why.

Comment: @steabert On a German keyboard `-` and `.` are directly adjacent to each other ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
program main
implicit none
integer :: param
parameter (param=((0-565)))
! integer, parameter :: param = -565 ! suggest replacing two lines above with this
print*,"param =",param
end program main
```

sets param to -565, as confirmed by both g95 and gfortran. The comment line uses a suggested modern syntax, assuming param is of the integer data type.

Comment: Thanks. I can't change the base package I'm working with, but I appreciate the suggestion.